# Русские символы при декодировании CSR(PEM) через OpenSSL.Net

Tags: c#, .net, openssl

Пытаюсь декодировать запрос на сертификат через OpenSSL.NET(https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net). Проблема возникает из-за символов. Русскосимвольные строки превращаются в "?????".

Т.е.:

```
    X509Request csr = new X509Request(File.ReadAllText("./test.req"));
    Console.WriteLine(csr.Subject.Common);
```

Выводит ерунду. Подскажите, как правильно декодировать?

Но, если попытаться вывести `Console.WriteLine(csr.Subject.ToString())` - то русские символы заменяться на `OU=\D0\A0\D1\83\D0\BA\D0\BE\D0\B2\D0\BE\D0\B4\D1\81\D1\82\D0\B2\D0\BE`, а не `OU=Руководство`
Если бы вместо '\' были бы '%' - это был бы URL-encoded, что очень странно.

Comment: X509Request csr = new X509Request(File.ReadAllText("./test.req", Encoding.UTF8)); Так?

Comment: Нет, он изначально в -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- тарабарщина -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- Так, что перекладывать файл смысла нет. Я думаю, что есть другие методы.